# Is there way to compare two videos frame by frame similar to the cmp program which compares byte by byte?

Tags: mp4

I have two copies of a video (an MP4) which appear identical having the same content, length, file size, resolution and Frames Per Second rate. I believe one is a copy of the other. However, when I compare them using cmp in bash I get:

```
25080261 316 176
25080262 200 240
25080263 316 163
25080264 341 370
25080265 153  32
25080266 110 222
25080267 176 137
25080268 371 176
25080269 345 371
25080270 357  73
25080271 114  23
25080272 274 257
25080273 216 243
25080274 322  64
25080275 374 277
25080276  72 116
25080277 221 244
25080278 362  74
25080279  50 312
25080280 127 125
25080281  15   3
25080282 160 134
25080283 151 332
25080284 253  52
25080285 334 167
25080286 341 370
25080287  47  11
25080288 250  52
25080289 330  66
25080290 250 252
25080291 236  47
25080292 300 260
25080293 366  75
25080294 150 232
25080295 326 365
25080296 303  60
25080297 150 332
25080298   3   0
25080299 374 177
25080300 141 330
25080301 243 250
25080302 376 277
25080303  76 217
25080304 276 257
25080305 332  66
25080306 334 267
25080307 242 350
25080308  17 203
25080309 356 173
25080310 245 151
25080311   1 300
25080312 317 363
25080313 343  70
25080314  44 311
25080315 203 240
25080316  12 202
25080317 206 141
25080318  45 311
25080319 167 235
25080320 172 336
```

It seems like they are identical for the first 25 MB, then they are different for 60 bytes and then the same again until the end (they are each 32.9 MiB long, according to Dolphin). How can this be? I was wondering if this is just the result of some quirk in the MP4 standard that specifies some sort of data structure here that holds data specific to the individual files, or there are actual differences between these videos. I have other MP4s that display a similar strange behavior. So I was wondering if there is a tool that can be used to compare these videos frame by frame to reveal whether these differences a few bytes long give rise to actual differences in the content of the videos. Is there such a tool?